# Which should I use the www folder for cordova iOS project?

Tags: ios, cordova, build

**root/www** files in the project does not work when I put it here
iOS platform **project/www** files in running.
but Cordova build can be reset and check this folder by deleting files?

Which is the correct folder for the project files? and how to prevent file loss during builder?

Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

The correct folder for developing is the www in root.

If you don't want to use cordova build over and over again, you can symlink the content of this folder to the content of the platform www folder.

Or you can write a script, which is running before compiling. This script copies the content to the www folders.

**Attention:**

Don't copy the whole folder to the platform folders, because in the platform www are some specific scripts, depending of your OS.